# readOGR feature mismatch with KML

Tags: r, kml, rgdal

I'm trying to read a kml [from this kmz I unzipped](http://smn.cna.gob.mx/tools/RESOURCES/estacion/EstacionesClimatologicas.kmz)
however, when I try to read a layer from it (as I've done it with previous kmzs) it says:

```
library(rgdal)
unzip("EstacionesClimatologicas.kmz")
ogr <- readOGR("doc.kml", "Puebla")
```

which gives the following output and error:

```
OGR data source with driver: KML 
Source: "doc.kml", layer: "Puebla"
with 117 features
It has 2 fields
Error in readOGR("doc.kml", "Puebla") : Feature mismatch
```

when I check

```
  ogrInfo("doc.kml", "Puebla")
```

says it's wkbPoint with 3 dimensions,
How can I get this to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into the code for `rgdal`, it seems to read 117 feature IDs, but the call the the OGR C code only returns 99 features. I can't see anything in the KML that might explain why 18 features get dropped.

Try the `sf` package, which does work nicely, and reads all 117 features:

```
> library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.5.1, GDAL 2.1.2, proj.4 4.9.3, lwgeom 2.3.1 r15264
> p = st_read("./doc.kml","Puebla")
Reading layer `Puebla' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/GE/doc.kml' using driver `LIBKML'
Simple feature collection with 117 features and 11 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XYZ
bbox:           xmin: -98.8197 ymin: 17.9794 xmax: -96.7933 ymax: 20.7483
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
> class(p)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

Works well.

If you really need `sp` class objects, you can convert the above:

```
> ps = as(p,"Spatial")
> class(ps)
[1] "SpatialPointsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
> names(ps)
 [1] "Name"         "description"  "timestamp"    "begin"        "end"         
 [6] "altitudeMode" "tessellate"   "extrude"      "visibility"   "drawOrder"   
[11] "icon"
```

There may be other solutions to reading geometries with Z dimensions directly with `rgdal`, but this works nicely!

Note you don't need to unzip the kmz, you can read directly from it:

```
> p = st_read("../EstacionesClimatologicas.kmz","Puebla")
Reading layer `Puebla' from data source `/home/rowlings/Downloads/EstacionesClimatologicas.kmz' using driver `LIBKML'
Simple feature collection with 117 features and 11 fields
geometry type:  POINT
```

Comment: How can you watch the C code?

Comment: I didn't step into the C code, its just the return from a .Call in the R code had fewer features. This line: https://github.com/cran/rgdal/blob/4b601edc83c6899d3d9a52e5ca313892d0daab6e/R/ogr_sp.R#L194 eventually triggering the error on line 256.